# Correctly catch aiohttp TimeoutError when using asyncio.gather

Tags: python, concurrency, aiohttp, python-asyncio

It is my first question here on Stack Overflow so I apologize if I did something stupid or missed something.

I am trying to make asynchronous aiohttp GET requests to many api endpoints at a time to check  the status of these pages: the result should be a triple of the form 
(*url*, *True*, *"200"*) in case of a working link and (*url*, *False*, *response_status*) in case of a "problematic link". This is the atomic function for each call:

```py
async def ping_url(url, session, headers, endpoint):

    try:
        async with session.get((url + endpoint), timeout=5, headers=headers) as response:
            return url, (response.status == 200), str(response.status)
    except Exception as e:
        test_logger.info(url + ": " + e.__class__.__name__)
        return url, False, repr(e)
```

These are wrapped into a function using asyncio.gather() which also creates the aiohttp Session:

```py
async def ping_urls(urllist, endpoint):

   headers = ... # not relevant

   async with ClientSession() as session:
        try:
            results = await asyncio.gather(*[ping_url(url, session, headers, endpoint) \
                      for url in urllist],return_exceptions=True)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))
   return results
```

The whole called from a main that looks like this:

```py
    urls = ... # not relevant
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(ping_urls(urls, endpoint))

    except Exception as e:
        pass
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

This works most of the time, but if the list is pretty long, I noticed that as soon as I get one

```
TimeoutError
```

the execution loop stops and I get TimeoutError for all other urls after the first one that timed out. If I omit the timeout in the innermost function I get somehow better results, but then it is not that fast anymore. Is there a way to control the Timeouts for the single api calls instead of a big general timeout for the whole list of urls?

Any kind of help would be extremely appreciated, I got stuck with my bachelor thesis because of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try setting a session timeout for your client session. This can be done like:

```
async def ping_urls(urllist, endpoint):
    headers = ... # not relevant

    timeout = ClientTimeout(total=TIMEOUT_SECONDS)
    async with ClientSession(timeout=timeout) as session:
        try:
            results = await asyncio.gather(
               *[
                    ping_url(url, session, headers, endpoint)
                    for url in urllist
                ],
                return_exceptions=True
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))

        return results
```

This should set the ClientSession instance to have `TIMEOUT_SECONDS` as the timeout. Obviously you will need to set that value to something appropriate!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the exceptions as well. I then found the hint, that I can also show the type of the Exception. And with that create appropriate Exception handling.

```
try: ...
except Exception as e:
     print(f'Error: {e} of Type: {type(e)}')
```

So, with this you can find out, what kind of errors occur and you can catch and handle them individually.

e.g.

```
try: ...
except aiohttp.ClientConnectionError as e:
    # deal with this type of exception
except aiohttp.ClientResponseError as e:
    # handle individually
except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError as e:
    # these kind of errors happened to me as well
```